# Genymotion stuck on splash screen

Tags: genymotion

My peer's laptop turned off due to power failure while genymotion was running. Unfortunately, after restarting the Xubuntu 14.04 machine, genymotion stopped working. It always get stuck on the startup splash screen. I tried reinstalling genymotion and virtualbox several times, all in vain. Seems to be the problem with user authentication.

This is the log file:-

```
Feb 22 19:37:20 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Feb 22 19:37:20 [Genymotion] [Warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
Feb 22 19:37:20 [Genymotion] [Warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
Feb 22 19:37:21 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
Feb 22 19:37:21 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion 2.6.0
Feb 22 19:37:21 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("./genymotion")
Feb 22 19:37:21 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x86/"
Feb 22 19:37:21 [Genymotion] [Debug] Getting currently authenticated user from  local cache
Feb 22 19:37:24 [Genymotion] [Debug] [HttpRequest::exec] Request timeout (code: 0 ) : "/launchpad/last_version/linux/x86/"
Feb 22 19:37:24 [Genymotion] [Error] Network error while retrieving JSON content:  0
Feb 22 19:37:24 [Genymotion] [Error] [getGenymotionLastVersion] Bad request: "/launchpad/last_version/linux/x86/"
Feb 22 19:37:24 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to get last Genymotion version number from server:  0
Feb 22 19:37:25 [Genymotion] [Warning] QIODevice::read: device not open
Feb 22 19:37:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Status: 0
Feb 22 19:37:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Content: ""
Feb 22 19:37:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Reply error: "Operation canceled" ( 5 )
Feb 22 19:37:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] last error msg: "Invalid reply from server"
Feb 22 19:37:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [login] Trying to authenticate  "kaveri kumar"
Feb 22 19:37:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] Trying to logout user
Feb 22 19:37:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/"
Feb 22 19:37:26 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done
Feb 22 19:37:26 [Genymotion] [Debug] [login] Login process result: 1
Feb 22 19:37:26 [Genymotion] [Debug] [login] User authenticated: "kaveri kumar"
```

And there's nothing more to it other than this.

EDIT- "kaveri kumar" is her user name for her genymotion account. I fail to understand even though I entered `Yes` while prompted to delete log files, her user name is still saved somewhere in the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't removing the configuration file in `/home/.config/Genymobile`. Removing that and other genymotion files and then reinstalling genymotion fixed the problem. Like I said in the question, the user name and password were still saved and they were probably causing the problem.

Answer (score 18):

I saw something similar... Resolved by using "Run as admin".

Cheers,

Comment: Xubuntu has no concept of "Run as admin". even if you meant sudo, that's not a proper answer.

Comment: yes, because Genymotion does not have the right to delete lock file in Genymotion's directory so we need run as administrator for full privileges to delete lock file

Answer (score 13):

You do not need to re-install Genymotion or deleting .config/Genymobile . What you need to delete is a single file which is the ~user/.config/Genymotion.conf.lock file.

Once deleted, the seems-to-be freezing "loading plugin" windows will proceed.

Comment: Thanks man. You saved my day. This answer deserves 100 upvotes.

Comment: I don't have the .config folder where is this in Windows?

Comment: I've tried to find it, not sure, but maybe it's under `C:\Users\coolstorybob\AppData\Local\Genymobile`.

Answer (score 2):

I opened the genymotion as administrator(run as administrator) and problem solved

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had an old VirtualBox version, it worked after installing latest and restarting my Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this was opening VirtualBox went to File > Check for Updates. Updated VirtualBox to the latest version. Then ran Genymotion with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to say that I had the same issue and deleting and re-installing Genymotion fixed my issue.

Comment: As it seems you did a proper uninstallation somehow which I failed to do that time and hence genymotion's configuration file and other files weren't deleting.

Answer (score 0):

My experience was a bit different on my Mac. To fix the issue, I removed and reinstalled Genymotion. Before starting, I ran this command `find ~ -maxdepth 3 -iname '*Genymotion*'`. It showed me a list of Saved State for Genymotion and I just removed all of them. In my case, I deleted the following files:

```
rm Library/Preferences/com.genymobile.Genymotion.plist 
rm Library/Preferences/com.yourcompany.genymotion.plist 
rm -rf Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.yourcompany.genymotion.savedState
```

Answer (score 0):

My Genymotion got stuck on the "loading plugins" screen, and then I found this post. Bigver's answer didn't help me at first, because I use Windows 10 and Genymotion 2.9.0, I cannot find the .config folder nor the file that he mentioned. This problem driven me crazy that night when I got it.

However, as Bigver's suggestion, the problem is in the 'Users' folder. I came up with the solution and it fixed my problem:

1. Create a new user account.
2. Make that account Administration
3. Login to that user account and go to the Users folder (normally, it is C:\Users\"YourUserName")
4. Copy the AppData folder and .VirtualBox folder to some place else (e.g. ABC folder)
5. Logout of the new user and login back to your main user.
6. Delete the Genymotion related folders/files and replace them with folders/files in ABC folder.
7. Delete the new user (optional).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

run genymotion in admin mode, and refresh your device

Answer (score 0):

Had this just now.

I don't have hyperv enabled. ( so it's not related)

But I did play with my windows settings 2 days ago with enabling this :

[image]

Since that change I wasn't enable to run geny.

Removing it ( and restart) - made genymotion to run again :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kill genymotion in task manager, empty the %temp% directory, clear cache in genymotion commandline and start the genymotion GUI as administrator. that worked for me perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Genymotion
2. Open VirtualBox
3. Open Genymotion again

This worked for me